# GTM sets screenname to (not set)

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to send `screen-view hits` to `Google Analytics` using `Google Tag Manager`, but in the real time view it is showing screenName value as `(not set)`. Actual screenNames are also shown but along with them `(not set)` is also reported. Can someone please point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have set it up is to add a new tag to be able to track the screen-view separately:

[----> Full config image example here <----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H93d3.png)

1. New tag in the GTM container with "**Screen View**" Track type

---

2. Add in "Fields to Set":

#### Field Name

*screenName*            //Yes, exactly like that

#### Value

*{{Item Name}}*         // Yes, exactly like that

---

3. Triggering: add a new trigger configuration with

#### Trigger Type

*Custom*

#### Trigger fires on

**Some events**
*Event Name* **equals** *view_item*

---

Then, on the Android tracking code:

**Make sure you track it like this:**

```
String yourScreenNameString = "Screen One"; //This is an example
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, yourScreenNameString);
_firebase.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, bundle);
```

[----> Example of how the GTM looks <----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a054u.png)

Comment: Yeah, Fixed it forgot to close this question. Anyways thanks your implementation is correct, accepting it for future reference.

Comment: One confirmation still, once you set Firebase with GTM, events won't be pushed directly to Firebase Analytics anymore we need to create tags in GTM ?

Comment: Awesome! Regarding Firebase, you then need to add a new tag in your GTM with the Firebase tag type with the action "Add Event". Then you will start receiving them again.

Comment: Firing rule for the new tag should be "All Events", will it push data to firebase or We need to manually map it?

Comment: Indeed, firing triggers as "All Events". You do not need to manually map it, it should work just like that. Just remember that the data will be available in Firebase (refreshed) every 4 hours -more or less-.